# Ищу плагин для машинного перевода в Sublime text

Tags: sublime-text-3

Ищу плагин для Sublime text, чтобы можно было переводить текст на русский, просто выделив его и нажав кнопки, или через меню.

Comment: Обязательно именно плагин? Есть программы отдельные

Answer (score 0):

Есть такой плагин для Yandex Translate. Называется YandexTranslate, https://packagecontrol.io/packages/YandexTranslate

На всякий случай, если вы считаете, что машинный перевод генерирует качественный текст, то это не так. Для нормального перевода нужно, чтобы принял участие переводчик-человек, иначе качество в любом случае будет "на отшибись".

Comment: увы этот плагин уже не работает, как и гугл такой же....